# In terms of performance, which is better: foo.setVisibility(View.GONE) or parent.removeView(foo)?

Tags: java, android, performance

I've been searching related forums about this but not one (yet) has detailed which one of these combo methods `foo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` + `foo.setVisibility(View.GONE)`
and `parent.addView(foo)` + `parent.removeView(foo)` is better in terms of **performance** or energy consumption...

Comment: Not my downvote, but `INVISIBLE` and `GONE` do very different things.  The former keeps the layout item in the actual layout, but not visible, and the latter completely removes the item.  My guess is that your use case, not performance, would be the deciding factor for which one you use.

Comment: Obviously if you remove a view, it won't be part of the layout and be "more performant" ,  but that only really matters within a list element probably

Comment: Keep in mind: premature optimisation is the root of all evil.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @TimBiegeleisen :) You're right. The use case is the deciding factor. Well then, addView()/removeView wins in one part of my project.

Answer (score 2):

```
foo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
foo.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

is preferred over

```
parent.addView(foo)
parent.removeView(foo)
```

if you want to show/hide frequently.

Comment: Thanks for your response. :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your implementation. But in most cases it doesnt matter.

Your custom `View`may have got a 'huge' constructor or some methods are overloaded using time/processor consumed calculations.

Nonetheless, in case of usual view (e.g., a `TextView`) it really doesnt matter.

if the visibility state equals gone  no methods of this view are used. While layout rendering this view is ignored.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input :)
You're right. It's all about the implementation and it's a case to case basis.

So in the end, in one part of the project I'm working on, I'll use addView/removeView then. I will be needing the event-based methods, besides, it's to make my customviews take on the role typically taken by Fragments.

Answer (score 1):

Use View.GONE on views that don't consume a lot of memory (like a TextView) and use parent.removeView(view) on views that are a lot of memory (like a WebView)

Comment: Thanks for your input! :)

Answer (score 0):

Invisible views are measured but not drawn. Gone views are not measured. So there is a slight performance difference.

Comment: Um.. I was asking about setVisibility() versus addView()/removeView here. Not View.INVISIBLE versus View.GONE :)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely VISIBLE and GONE is better compared to adding and removing views.

1) Like others have said, it definitely has better performance than actually removing and adding views

But the next point according to me is more important

2) You can still do a lot of things with the View(getText or setText) etc with the views even when you do a GONE on the view, but if it you remove and add views, the View itself does not exist, preventing you from doing anything with it

Comment: In the end, it's a case to case basis. One has an advantage over the other and vice versa. My take is `setVisibility()` is better when you want to jump from showing one view to another _frequently_ and if the views are smaller; `addView()` + `removeView()` combo is better for Custom Views with lots of other elements inside them and when you don't want to leave the views active and accessible when they are not attached to the parent.

Thanks for your input, by the way~